# Django on uWSGI emailing issues

Tags: django, uwsgi

When switched to uWSGI with Django app (Debian server), for some unknown reason sending emails from Django does not reach recipients anymore.

My uWSGI configuration is:

```
[uwsgi]
touch-reload = /opt/server/uwsgi
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
workers = 2
virtualenv = /opt/server/envs/server
chdir = /opt/server/envs/server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/app
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHander()
wsgi-file = /opt/server/settings/wsgi.py
```

I can send email when using a command:

```
echo "This is my email text." | mail -s "This is the subject" my@email.com
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Shouldn't have anything to do with uwsgi. What email backend have you configured Django to use?

Comment: Nothing is set, I suppose it fallbacks to the default. However, before it was working just fine...

Comment: The default is the SMTP backend. I can't see how uwsgi would have any effect on that though. Check /var/log/mail.log to see if there is anything in there? Django would log failed SMTP requests so most likely the mail is getting lost somewhere else.

Comment: In the mail log I see only emails being send by fail2ban. No records of Django activity whatsoever (I use postfix).

Comment: Weird. Only thing I can think of is to check that `EMAIL_BACKEND` really isn't being set in your settings and that Django itself isn't logging an error when trying to send email.

Comment: We have Opbeat setup so any error would be logged... And `EMAIL_BACKEND` is definitely not set... Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: The most likely reason is that the app now runs as a different user and/or with different permissions. I'd suggest looking in that direction :)